# Wrap text while keeping position of objects intact relative to each other

Tags: css

Currently I have the following set up in my web app, where on the left there is a up/down vote, followed by some text that a user inputs.

```
 -----   -------------------------------
|up   | |some one liner text            |
|down |  -------------------------------
|vote | 
 -----
```

If the text gets too long, it does wrap ok, but then its position relative to the up/down vote system gets completely jiggered up, as seen in the following:

```
//current undesired outcome
 -----   
|up   | 
|down |  
|vote |  -------------------------------
 -----  |some longer text goes here, it |
        |also magically centers if it   |
        |      goes several lines       |
         -------------------------------
```

I have set up my CSS to be relative simple, so couldn't figure out why when the text wrap occurs it goes all the way to center below the left callbox.  Thanks for your help!

```
.parent-div {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.votebox {
    float: left;
    width:40px; 
    height:50px;
    //there are more sub classes in here for the up/down vote arrows but I didn't include
}

.usertext{
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough HTML and content to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is how the markup looks like:

```
<div class="left">
  up down vote
</div>

<div class="right">
  text...
</div>
```

If so, just put `overflow:hidden` on the right DIV:

```
.left{
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.right{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JsfB7/))

Comment: Thanks - didn't know it was just a matter of overflow:hidden. Will try out as soon as I get a chance :)